# Is it possible to block website when not on VPN?

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I have a website I access only when connected to VPN. Is it possible to block access to this website when I'm not using VPN?

I can block access to websites in hosts file, but this completely blocks access, even when using VPN. I would like to make sure I never visit that website without VPN, but when using VPN then I should have normal access to the website.

I only access this website with Firefox or Chrome, so blocking in these browsers is good enough.

Comment: You should add your OS and router to the post and advise if its OK to do this on your router. In generic terms you can firewall the IP associated with the site to disallow it from going through your regulat (ethernet) interface.

Comment: @davidgo I've been looking into this with my router, but that is not something that can be changed quickly, when going on and off VPN.

Comment: @davidgo Could you please advise how to configure Windows firewall for this? Or maybe some 3rd party firewall if windows doesn't allow that. I see that TS mentioned Windows-10 tag. So your answer will help both of us. Thank you!

Comment: @davidgo  I tried Windows 7 firewall and see that it can filter only based on IP, not DNS.

Comment: @vladnlvakovsky it is unlikely you will find a firewall that filters.on DNS, as the performance penalty is massive and it would be difficult if not impossible to hook into the OS.  I can't advise firewall software or setup on Windows.